# Resolving 'No key Defined' errors while using OnModelCreating with ApplicationDbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-model-builder

I've been trying to create navigation properties for my collection types and I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969004/how-do-i-configure-a-navigation-property-to-the-same-table-in-entity-framework) of how one person accomplished it using OnModelCreating. I gave it a try in my MVC 5 application and I recieved this error when trying to update my database:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> BlogEngine.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   BlogEngine.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is
>   based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based
>   on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

### How do I resolve these 'No key Defined' errors?

I did some searching and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit) for one users problem, but his needs were different than mine. The solutions seemed pretty convoluted for what I am trying to do.

This is the code that causes the issue:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }
        //public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().
                 HasOptional(e => e.Tags).
                 WithMany().
                 HasForeignKey(m => m.Tags_Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().
                 HasOptional(e => e.Posts).
                 WithMany().
                 HasForeignKey(m => m.Posts_Id);
        }

    }
```

Here are my to models with the many to many relationship:

[Post.cs model on Gist](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/3ec0f8a5a36e4e5cacd0)

[Tag.cs  model on Gist](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/9327e9b3e4045c93ea20)

---

Update to show IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any entity with name IdentityUserLogin ?

Comment: It's built into the MVC 5 template

Comment: Can u check that is there any key defined for that ? Because error states that there is no key for this table.

Comment: I am not sure where to define keys, I would assume that if the code came with the template from microsoft it would have them. I suppose that may be part of the solution to my question...

Comment: OK please include the Entity IdentittyUserLogin in question.

Comment: It is not method or property it is class and will be defined in Models.

Comment: OK in IdentityModel.cs check for the class IdentityUserLogin class or include code of this cs file in question.

Comment: updated to show application user (this is whats left in  that file )

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474662/map-tables-using-fluent-api-in-asp-net-mvc5-ef6 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might have to add something like the following to `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
```

**See also:**

- [Map tables using fluent api in asp.net MVC5 EF6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474662/map-tables-using-fluent-api-in-asp-net-mvc5-ef6)
- [User in Entity type MVC5 EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6)

Answer (score 10):

I think the issue is that you have removed the calling of `base` class from `OnModelCreating`. Try adding that also as shown below

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Your configuration goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late response, and this may only work for people working off tutorials or school projects!

For me, just deleting the database, .mdf, and migrations folder fixed it. Now, I don't know if you are using migrations, but this worked for me.

I'm a novice, but what I've noticed is that Identity is very finicky with keys. Deleting the migration has helped with every (godforsaken) migration problem I've hit with my project.

Comment: That's not much of a solution though, is it? Any *real world* deployment needs migrations, deleting the database and starting over is not an option.